# Impossible to install EPEL 5.4 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, virtualbox

I'm a noob of Ubuntu.

I'm following some instructions to install `epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm` on my virtual Ubuntu 14.04 hosted in VirtualBox.

I tried the command:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

But it says that `the host download.fedora.redhat.com is unknown`.

So i found this working url:

> https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/

In this url there is available the `epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm`.

So i tried the command:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

But I obtain this error:

```
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.9Y0b8t: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, ID key 217521f6: NOKEY
error: Failed dipendencies:
redhat-release >= 5 is needed by epel-release-5-4.noarch
```

Any idea to how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: EPEL is for RedHat and RedHat-based systems which run on RPM packages.  Ubuntu doesn't use RPM packages, so therefore you can't use EPEL for Ubuntu

Answer (score 7):

Just to make sure - you realize that EPEL is repo for redhat/rpm based distrubutions, not Ubuntu?

Of course, in the end, if really necessary, you can try to use rpm packages converted to debs (with alien) - but that may lead to many strange and difficult to resolve in a nice way issues (starting with dependencies, as in your example)

I'd rather search in Ubuntu repos for whatever you're looking for. Especially if you're a noob - since trying to use other distributions packages may not be an easy way to go.

Other than that - the unknown host would point at dns issues I guess, probably related to your virtual guest configuration.
Failed dependencies - well, that's where your troubles start. It's not redhat, so it complains about unsatisfied dependency.
I doubt you'll be able to do anything that way with your repo. You can force installing the package, but I'd say there will be not much advantage from doing that.

If you really need epel for some reason, maybe you should rather start using Fedora or CentOS?

Comment: Well, I can try to install a CentOs version on VirtualBox. There is not a specific reason for my Ubuntu choice: I only needed a Linux virtualized machine. I didn't know that every version is too different from others. Thanks however for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

adds a **RPM repository** on **RPM based** distributions. In other words, **forget it**!

Ubuntu is based on Debian (**DEB based**) and for this reason, you way is completely wrong.